# Display Sticky button above of Toolbar

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have following layout :

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/Toolbar"/>

    <com.sample.android.scrolltricks.ObservableScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView style="@style/Item"
                           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                           android:src="@drawable/london_flat"
                           tools:ignore="contentDescription"/>

                <View android:id="@+id/placeholder"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="@dimen/sticky_height"/>

                <View style="@style/Item.Bottom"/>
                <View style="@style/Item.Bottom.Alt"/>
                <View style="@style/Item.Bottom"/>
                <View style="@style/Item.Bottom.Alt"/>
                <View style="@style/Item.Bottom"/>
                <View style="@style/Item.Bottom.Alt"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button android:id="@+id/sticky" style="@style/Sticky"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </com.sample.android.scrolltricks.ObservableScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code to display sticky button when scroll :

```
override fun onScrollChanged(scrollY: Int) {
        sticky.translationY = Math.max(
            placeholder.top - resources.getDimension(R.dimen.sticky_height) / 2,
            scrollY.toFloat() - 65
        )
    }
```

Sticky button is shown under Toolbar, I want to show it partially above the Toolbar. (`scrollY.toFloat() - 65`)

Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in your layout you can't bring that `Button` above the `ScrollView`. 
Your `Button` is a child of `FrameLayout`, which is a child of `ScrollView` itself, so that its drawing area is limited by parent's bounds.

It's better to solve such tasks by wrapping everything in `CoordinatorLayout` and then apply a custom `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` on the `View` you want to have a specific positioning.

Hope it helps.